# CometD NodeJS handshake failing

Tags: node.js, ssl, cometd

I have a node implementation of cometD, what I am trying to do is have an end point that can send a GET to, and then have it publish a message in the cometD channel.

The handshakes keep failing and I'm not really sure why.

How do I enable more verbose logging on either side to get to the bottom of this ?
Or if there's something obvious I'm missing please let me know.

Server code

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const httpPort = 3000;
const cometdPort = 3001;

const sslCfg = {
    "keyPath": "/path/to/key.pem",
    "certPath": "/path/to/bundle.crt"
}


// commetD stuff
const https = require('https');


const sslConfig = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(sslCfg.keyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(sslCfg.certPath)
}

const cometd = require('cometd-nodejs-server');
const cometdServer = cometd.createCometDServer(sslConfig);


const cometdServer = https.createServer(cometdServer.handle);
cometdServer.listen(cometdPort, function() {
    // Your application code here.
    console.log(`CometD server set up `);
});

const demoChannel = cometdServer.createServerChannel('/techDemo');

demoChannel.addListener('message', function(session, channel, message, callback) {
    callback();
});
const myIDs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./idMap.json'));

app.get("/:myId", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.myId;
    const respObject = {
        "selectionId": myIDs[id]
    }
    res.send(respObject);
    demoChannel.publish(false, JSON.stringify(respObject));
})

https.createServer(sslConfig, app).listen(httpPort);
```

Client code

```js
require('cometd-nodejs-client').adapt();

// Your normal CometD client application here.
var lib = require('cometd');
var cometd = new lib.CometD();

// Configure the CometD object.
cometd.configure({
  url: 'https://myserver.com:3001/cometd'
});


// Handshake with the server.
cometd.handshake(function (h) {
  if (h.successful) {
    console.log(`Handshake successful`)
    // Subscribe to receive messages from the server.
    cometd.subscribe('/techDemo', function (m) {
      var dataFromServer = m.data;
      // Use dataFromServer.
      console.log(dataFromServer);
    });
  } else {
    console.error(`Handshake failed`)
    console.error(h);
  }

});
```

Handshake errors

```json
{
  id: '1',
  successful: false,
  channel: '/meta/handshake',
  failure: {
    websocketCode: 1000,
    reason: 'Error',
    connectionType: 'websocket',
    transport: { envelopes: {}, timeouts: {}, webSocket: [WebSocket] },
    message: {
      id: '1',
      version: '1.0',
      minimumVersion: '1.0',
      channel: '/meta/handshake',
      supportedConnectionTypes: [Array],
      advice: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  id: '2',
  successful: false,
  channel: '/meta/handshake',
  failure: {
    reason: 'write EPROTO 29280:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\rec_layer_s3.c:1546:SSL alert number 40\n',
    exception: undefined,
    httpCode: 0,
    connectionType: 'long-polling',
    transport: {
      status: 0,
      statusText: 'write EPROTO 29280:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\rec_layer_s3.c:1546:SSL alert number 40\n',
      readyState: 4,
      responseText: '',
      open: [Function (anonymous)],
      setRequestHeader: [Function (anonymous)],
      send: [Function (anonymous)],
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      _config: [Function (anonymous)],
      context: undefined,
      withCredentials: true,
      onload: [Function (anonymous)],
      onerror: [Function (anonymous)],
      onabort: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    message: {
      id: '2',
      version: '1.0',
      minimumVersion: '1.0',
      channel: '/meta/handshake',
      supportedConnectionTypes: [Array],
      advice: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```